# Secrets file ignored when pushing to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am deploying a [CONSUL](http://consulproject.org/en/) app to Heroku and the logs say that I am missing the 'secret_token' and 'secret_key_base' in my 'config/secrets.yml' file.

When I try to commit it, git ignores it. This is when I commit the whole 'config' folder:

```
create mode 100644 config/routes/verification.rb
create mode 100644 config/schedule.rb
create mode 100644 config/secrets.yml.example
create mode 100644 config/sitemap.rb
```

It only reads the 'secrets.yml.example'.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Check if this file name pattern or location is included in your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

The '.gitignore' file in the root directory of your project probably has an entry for secrets.yml

Removing this line would allow you to stage, commit, and deploy your secrets file, but this is not recommended if you're pushing your code to a site like GitHub, where others can look inside your project. You should be trying to set the secrets up as environment variables via the Heroku admin panel for your app instead.

Comment: There's no .gitignore file in the root directory, that's why I'm confused as to why it is ignoring it. Do you have any ideas why it might be?

Comment: Perhaps there's one in the config directory, or in any one of its parent directories (up until the project root)?